# Accessing a JSON var wthout using item.item = string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the array

```
var weekdayColor = {
        sunday : 'red',       // sunday
        monday : 'blue',      // monday
        tuesday: 'white',     // tuesday
        wednesday: 'black',    
        thursday: 'green',     
        friday: 'yellow',  
        saturday: 'orange'     
    }
```

I want to be able to do something along the lines of `weekcayColor[0]` to get `sunday`:

Here is the JavaScript I wrote for an interview which was already turned in.. I know there is an easier way to do this. The first var `weekdayColor` CANNOT BE CHANGED; also `weekdayColor.sunday` returns `red`.

Perhaps I am using the wrong date method or accessing the var incorrectly?

```
var weekdayColor = {
        sunday : 'red',       // sunday
        monday : 'blue',      // monday
        tuesday: 'white',     // tuesday
        wednesday: 'black',     // wednessday
        thursday: 'green',     // thursday
        friday: 'yellow',    // friday
        saturday: 'orange'     // saturday
    }
    var weekday=new Array();
        weekday[0]="sunday";
        weekday[1]="monday";
        weekday[2]="tuesday";
        weekday[3]="wednesday";
        weekday[4]="thursday";
        weekday[5]="friday";
        weekday[6]="saturday";
    d = new Date;
    day = d.getDay();
    console.log(weekday[day]);
    a = weekday[day];
    function change(){
        var x = document.getElementById("weekday");
        x.innerHTML = a;
        x.style.color = weekdayColor[a];
    }
```

Comment: You're missing `var`s and arrau literals.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I believe it's fine because JavaScript Objects don't necessarily keep a cross-browser property ordering. So, you still need the `weekday` array for mapping. A bit of better formatting, code clean-up and usage of `[]` notation for array creation may have been better.

Comment: You can't access a JSON object property by an index value: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4231336/674700](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4231336/674700).

Comment: @AlexFilipovici You are confusing terms here. There is no such thing like JSON Object. Javascript has either Objects or Arrays (or simple datatypes like strings, number or booleans). JSON means javascript object notation and is a datatransfer format which bases upon javascript's object notation und thus is easily integrated into JS because if you parse it, you have a valid JS Object you can work with.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do. If you just want to change today element color need to modify `change()` as follows:

```
function change(day){
    var x = document.getElementById(day);       
    x.style.color = weekdayColor[day];
}
var d = new Date(),
    day = d.getDay(),
    a = weekday[day];

/* now call change passing day as argument*/
change(a);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rhHjn/1

Answer (score 0):

Easier would be to use an array of objects as following:

```
var weekday = [
   {name:"sunday",color:"red"},
   {name:"monday",color:"blue"},
   // and so on
]
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
d = new Date();
day = d.getDay();
weekday[day].name  // yields name
weekday[day].color // yields color
```

Alternatively you could write a prototype method:

```
Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
return ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']
       [this.getDay()];
}
```

and now

```
var d = new Date;
d.getDayName(); // this would actually give you the name of the day
```

Comment: I can't change the initial var

Comment: @Xeo You cannot access the keys of an object via Array Notation `[i]` because object keys are not ordered! Other than iterating over all properties of the object e.g. via a `for` loop you cannot tell, which keys it actually contains.