# How to get the index of json array

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

```
var data = [
    [{
        min: "3.00",
        max: "3.00",
        mom: "3.00",
        paramname: "HV_CAP_B",
        color: "#42426F"
    }, {
        min: "3.00",
        max: "3.00",
        mom: "3.00",
        paramname: "HV_CAP_B",
        color: "#42426F"
    }, {
        min: "3.00",
        max: "3.00",
        mom: "3.00",
        paramname: "HV_CAP_B",
        color: "#42426F"
    }]
]
```

Does anyone know how to get the index of min, max, mom?

Comment: what do you mean by "the index of"? aren't these three objects in an array, with the same values in every object in the array?

Comment: you have no "max" , just "mas" :p

Comment: Object properties are not indexed (they're actually not guaranteed to be ordered reliably across implementations).

Comment: Is there a reason why the json object contains nested arrays?

Comment: @KevinBowersox just saw that too.

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231327/index-value-of-array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read Json/Array string in Php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744280/read-json-array-string-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I fear i don't understand the question. But if you want to read for example the first `min` value of your object, you can do this :

```
var min = data[0][0].min;
```

If you want the second `min`, it's this :

```
var min2 = data[0][1].min
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop and add them in an array

```
   var min = [],
       mas=[];
   for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
        console.log("min = " + data[0][i].min + " mas = "+ data[0][i].mas)
        min.push(data[0][i].min);
        mas.push(data[0][i].mas);
    }

/*Output

min = 3.00 mas = 3.00
min = 3.00 mas = 3.00
min = 3.00 mas = 3.00

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get value with `data[0].min`